# PHP if statement comparison always returning true

Tags: php, mysql

My if statement is always returning true, and I cannot chase the problem.

The value of $currentMessageCount is 42, and lastMessageCount is 41.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT message_count, last_seen
                          FROM message_counter 
                          WHERE match_id = '$i'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$currentMessageCount = (int)$row["message_count"];
$lastMessageCount = (int)$row["last_seen"];
$result->free();

if ($currentMessageCount > $lastMessageCount) {

    this code is running

} elseif ($currentMessageCount === $lastMessageCount) {

    this code is also running!!

}
```

Edit:

This is the actual code sample, added as suggested:

```
//loop through and check new messages for all matches
for($i = 1; $i <= $numMatches; $i++) {

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT message_count, last_seen FROM message_counter WHERE match_id = '$i'");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $currentMessageCount = (int)$row["message_count"];
        $lastMessageCount = (int)$row["last_seen"];
        //free memory
        $result->free();

        //if new messages - get them, else - skip
        if ($currentMessageCount > $lastMessageCount) {
            $newMessages = true;
            //get NEW messages for that match
            $result = $mysqli->query("  SELECT all_messages.* FROM all_messages
                                        WHERE match_id = '$i' 
                                        AND message_number > '$lastMessageCount'");

            //loop through all messages in table
            $j = 0;
            $allMessages = [];
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $dateTime = $row["date_time"];
                $messageNumber = $row["message_number"];
                $messageBody = $row["message_body"];
                $matchID = $i;
                $senderID = $row["sender_id"];

                //message array for each message
                $messageData = ["dateTime" => $dateTime,
                                "messageNumber" => $messageNumber,
                                "currentMessageCount" => $currentMessageCount,
                                "lastMessageCount" => $lastMessageCount,
                                "messageBody" => $messageBody,
                                "matchID" => $matchID,
                                "senderID" => $senderID];

                //put in another array for response
                $allMessages[$j] = $messageData;
                $j++;
            }
            //free memory
            $result->free();

            //put each message set into array for each user
            $allMatchMessages[$i-1] = $allMessages;

        } elseif ($currentMessageCount === $lastMessageCount) {
            $newMessages = false;
        }
    }
```

The code is returning both the $messageData array full of data, and newMessages = false

Comment: _" this code is also running!!"_ Both can't run at the same time. If the first condition is always true, then only that block would run

Comment: I would check that the code in the ELSE block has not also been pasted into the IF block

Comment: My guess is the code in question is called twice. Place an `echo microtime(true);` in each code block to check.

Comment: Given the current code example, no one will be able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I will append the actual code to the post now

Comment: As others have stated, both cannot run at the same time. Make sure your code is the same as you've written here. If this code is ran in a loop of some sort it might just look like both are executed while really they're 2 different runs

Comment: @PhilS please try to include a [mcve] in the first revision when asking debugging-type questions like this.

Comment: result of microtime(true); 1504652563.9398 and 1504652563.9401

Comment: `$newMessages` is overwritten with each iteration of the outer for loop and will end up with the value assigned in the last iteration.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that is correct! Bed time I think!

Comment: @tadman noted, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$newMessages` is overwritten with each iteration of the outer `for` loop and will end up with the value assigned in the last iteration.

> The code is returning both the `$messageData` array full of data, and `$newMessages = false`

The apparent explanation for this is that `$messageData` is populated by early iterations of the for loop, and all subsequent iterations (or at least the last one) set `$newMessages` to false.

It looks like you could probably just eliminate the `elseif` block, and set `$newMessages` to `false` before the `for` loop. Actually, `$newMessages` probably isn't even necessary, because you can evaluate `$allMessages` as boolean after the for loop finishes. (If it's empty it will evaluate to false and vice versa.)